# Exercise on equivalent norms

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that 2 norms are equivalent in this space: $X=C^{1}([a,b])$ .

The first norm is the standard $ ||f||_{1} $. The second norm is $ ||f||_{x} = |f(a)| +  ||f^{'}||_{\infty} $.

I can do one inequality, namely  $ ||f||_{1} < C||f||_{x} $,  could you please help me to find the opposite inequality?

Thanks a lot

PS: for the first part I used the fact that $f(t) = f(a) + \int_a^tf^{'}(\tau)d\tau$

Comment: What makes you think they're equivalent?

Comment: This is an exercise given by a teacher, he told me that they are equivalent

Comment: I doubt it. Take a look at the sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ defined by $f_n(x) = \sin(2 nx)$ on $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did the right thing with that sequence but I tried to compute the norm in both cases and then let n go to + infinity. I got +infinity in both cases. So it isn't a contraddiction of the equivalence, right?

(For the standard norm I got 4*n, is correct?)

Comment: I added an answer, I hope it's clear.

Comment: Yes it's clear, thank you! I computed wrongly the integral, I am sorry. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $C^1([0,\pi])$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \sin(2nx).
$$

Note that
$$
\|f_n\|_1 = \int_0^\pi \lvert \sin(2nx) \rvert dx = \frac{1}{2n} \int_0^{2n\pi } \lvert \sin(x) \rvert dx
$$
Because $\lvert \sin(x) \rvert = \lvert \sin(x+\pi) \rvert$, we have 
$$
\|f_n\|_1 = \int_0^\pi \sin(x) dx = -\cos \pi + \cos(0)=2.
$$
But $f_n' = 2n \cos(2nx)$ so $\|f_n\|_x =2n$. This means $(f_n)_n$ is unbounded in $\|\cdot \|_x$ but bounded in $\|\cdot \|_1$, so the norms can't be equivalent.